# Create record with just attributes instead of a message in Python Logging

Tags: python, logging

Is there an easy way to create a log record in Python where instead of sending a message, you just send a list of attributes?

From what I understand, methods like [`logger.info`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/902196d867a34cc154fa9c861c883e69232251c6/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1726) and [`logger.debug`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/902196d867a34cc154fa9c861c883e69232251c6/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1720) are just methods to create log records at specific levels. These methods call the [`self._log`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/902196d867a34cc154fa9c861c883e69232251c6/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1496) method, which itself calls the [`self.makeRecord`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/902196d867a34cc154fa9c861c883e69232251c6/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1481) method.

If I wanted to create records where the message attribute is none, could I just call `logger.makeRecord`, passing `None` to message and a dictionary of attributes to the `extra` keyword argument? Or should I call `self._log` and pass those arguments? Or do neither of these work? Can I instead just pass `extra` to the `logger.info` method too?

Also, if this is possible, why is it not done more often? It seems like the ideal workflow would have only attributes being passed into a log record, and then the message would be compiled by the formatter after.

Sorry for so many mini-questions in this post.

Comment: You may be in the [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), could you explain _why_ you want `makeRecord` to take `extra` attrs?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you format your logging string to take those extra args? The `extra` kwarg is for this purpose explicitly. From their [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html):

```
FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(clientip)s %(user)-8s %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
d = {'clientip': '192.168.0.1', 'user': 'fbloggs'}
logger = logging.getLogger('tcpserver')
logger.warning('Protocol problem: %s', 'connection reset', extra=d)

# which prints this
2006-02-08 22:20:02,165 192.168.0.1 fbloggs  Protocol problem: connection reset
```

`extra` is for kwarg mapping, so if you wanted it to build a string for you, it can. 'message' is positional, so there's no ignoring it. However, there's nothing stopping you from providing an empty string `''` as the `message` positional arg